# How to use pyshical display when it connected instead of dummy display driver on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, display

I have Intel NUC with Ubuntu 18.04 which operates as server the most time. Sometimes SSH is not enough and I need to control it using Team Viewer. This is why I installed and set up xserver-xorg-video-dummy because Team Viewer requires some display. Everything is working fine but when I want to connect physical display (to control server without network) dummy display does not allow to use physical display and monitor is saying there is no signal. Is there a way to configure Ubuntu to use both displays physical and dummy but to make physical display the most wanted? I mean when I connect it Ubuntu uses it, when disconnect Ubuntu switches to dummy.

My working config for dummy /etc/X11/xorg.conf is the following:

```
# This xorg configuration file is meant to be used
# to start a dummy X11 server.
# For details, please see:
# https://www.xpra.org/xorg.conf

# Here we setup a Virtual Display of 1920x1080 pixels

Section "Device"
    Identifier "Configured Video Device"
    Driver "dummy"
    VideoRam 256000
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "Configured Monitor"
    HorizSync 5.0 - 1000.0
    VertRefresh 5.0 - 200.0
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Default Screen"
    Monitor "Configured Monitor"
    Device "Configured Video Device"
    DefaultDepth 24
    SubSection "Display"
        Depth 24
        Modes "1920x1080" "1280x720"
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Comment: dumb question, did you make sure to disable wayland/ log into a xorg desktop by default?

Comment: also would you be open to trying with : xvnc or xvfb, that being said either of those will probably also require you to be in xorg mode, not wayland

Comment: I'm having the same issue with Mint 20. Have you found a solution?

Comment: By the way I've found this other question https://askubuntu.com/questions/1229168/video-dummy-the-fake-display-with-without-monitor-connected-at-the-same-time that has one answer

Comment: Currently I don't use dummy display and Team Viewer. I'm using xrdp which allows headless remote desktop https://askubuntu.com/a/1409120/45969