# video-dummy - The Fake display with/without monitor connected at the same time

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, vnc

I have installed the `xserver-xorg-video-dummy-hwe-18.04` to let I use the VNC without needs to connect HDMI cable to my ubuntu machine.

I followed the [Topic here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453109/add-fake-display-when-no-monitor-is-plugged-in), and successfully able to use VNC connect to Ubuntu machine without plugged-in monitor.

However, there are side effect is that, if I connect the HDMI cable to the ubuntu machine, it will display _ (black screen with cursor blinking at the top) and not show `lightdm` login screen as expected.

If I remove `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` from directory, reboot, I can now back using the monitor plugged-in.

**Question**

Are there possible to able to use `video-dummy` with/without monitor at the same time? may be like secondary mirroring display mode. How to config `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` properly?

So that I can use the desktop no matter real monitor has connected to HDMI port or not.

Comment: Hi there, wondering if you were able to solve this problem. Am running into the same problem.

Comment: Hi @scalopus, I know it's been a while, but have you found a solution to your issue? If so, I'm now in your situation, i.e. followed the instructions in the topic you mentioned and now I do not have output when a real display is connected.

Answer (score 0):

Main problem here is that the KMS (Kernel Mode Setting) is on in modern kernels. This needs to be disabled by creating rules to modprobe depending your card:

For ATI graphics:

```
echo options radeon modeset=0 > /etc/modprobe.d/radeon-kms.conf
```

For Intel graphics:

```
echo options i915 modeset=0 > /etc/modprobe.d/i915-kms.conf
```

For Nvidia i suggest blacklisting nouveau driver and use vesa on xorg.conf

Now if your modeline is setted correctly you should be able to connect your monitor on the fly.

Comment: Is there a way to do that without disabling KMS? And what are the consequences of disabling it?

Comment: I have the same issue , here with nVidia , but all solutions I found, none worked.