# How do I add a xserver-xorg-video-dummy display to mirror the physical display?

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors

I run a home file server on Ubuntu 18.04, which normally doesn't have a monitor plugged in. I would like to be able to VNC into it, but I discovered that it doesn't start the X session until I plug in a monitor. So I installed xserver-xorg-video-dummy and created an `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file that uses the `dummy` driver.

It works great, but I still want to be able to plug in a physical monitor. However, since the `xorg.conf` file overrides my previous configuration, when I plug in a physical monitor, I just get a blank screen. I can still VNC in and see my desktop, but the physical monitor is blank.

I tried removing the 'dummy' `xorg.conf` file and running `sudo Xorg -configure` without X running in order to generate an `xorg.conf` file that I could then add the dummy display to as a mirror of the physical display, but the `Xorg -configure` command segfaults. I've read that `xorg.conf` is rarely used anymore, and that `Xorg -configure` is obsolete and should not be used, and regardless, the `Xorg -configure` segfault is not likely to be fixed any time soon.

Is there a way I can get both the physical monitor and the dummy monitor to work, without using an `xorg.conf` file?

Answer (score 0):

I found the reference here: [video-dummy - The Fake display with/without monitor connected at the same time](https://askubuntu.com/q/1229168/1018602).
You need to set KMS (Kernel Mode Setting) off.

For ATI graphics:

```
echo options radeon modeset=0 > /etc/modprobe.d/radeon-kms.conf
```

For Intel graphics:

```
echo options i915 modeset=0 > /etc/modprobe.d/i915-kms.conf
```

Works fine with ubuntu 20.04